# What is the difference between AND and WITH in general?

Tags: conjunctions, meaning

I, myself, a russian native, but still can't tell what is the real difference between **and** and **with** even in my own language. Is there definite demarcation line between those grammatical concepts? I'm looking for traces, marks, indicators on the basis of which one can easily say that X means "and" or "with".

This question is vexing me because I try to figure out and classify Chinese conjunctions, almost all of  which translated as **and** in English.

P.s. As one of the commentators pointed out:

- "John together with Mary" is grammatically singular
- "John and Mary together" is grammatically plural.
  That's a good indicator with which you can differentiate between **and** and **with**, but in chinese it's rather difficult, since words rarely have plural form.

Comment: "With" is not a conjunction; it is a preposition.

Comment: Ok, well, but in many cases one can substitute it with the other. ex: "I with him were walking" or "I and he were walking".

Comment: The question not about English language but about general language. In chinese there are hanzi 与,跟, 及 which sometimes being translated as "and" and sometimes as "with". In Russian you can switch "и" and "с" very frequently too.

Comment: I don't think there is a language universal difference.  In English, "John together with Mary" and "John and Mary together" mean the same, though the first is grammatically singular and the second grammatically plural.

Comment: You may be interested in the following "World Atlas of Language Structures" article by Leon Stassen and the accompanying map: [Noun Phrase Conjunction](http://wals.info/chapter/63). It says that not all languages have this kind of distinction. Some languages only have a word that means "with".

Comment: Great link. Thanks. I don't know why people are downvoiting :)

Comment: @coobit: 及 should generally be translated as 'and', not 'with', except in some texts before the Han Dynasty.

Comment: But WHY it was "with" before? What makes people think that  及 once was "with" and surely not "and"? I mean they are close in their meaning. How people can differentiate between them? What clues are their in their usage which gives away "with" or "and" connotation?

Comment: @coobit Well, conjunction isn't the only place where you can say 'with'. 及 no longer has a comitative use in modern Chinese (and hasn't had one for nearly two millennia): you can't say *及你一起去, but you can say {與, 跟}你一起去. However, we have evidence from pre-Han texts that 及 could previously be used like this, e.g. 及爾同死 (die with you) in the Classic of Poetry. As for why, well, it's called narrowing, a kind of semantic shift. In this case, it's possibly the result of a tendency towards paradigmatic economy, since we already have 與 and don't want a duplicate.

Comment: "John together with Mary" is grammatically singular
"John and Mary together" is grammatically plural.   That's just wrong.

Comment: semantically they are very different.  "John and Mary went to the opera" v. "John went to the opera with Mary".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are asking is 'What is the **universal** difference between English *with* and English *and* (or their Russian equivalents, for that matter), the question is wrongly formulated, and unanswerable, because other languages need not, and in fact do not, have lexical items with **all** the same syntactic and semantic properties English *with* and English *and* have. Your question should, therefore, as a minimum, be reworded in terms of a hypothetical (?unique!) difference between a would-be universal ?'conjunction function' **&** and a would-be universal 'comitative/groupal function' **C** (in the broadest possible sense of 'conjunction' and 'comitative'). The former, at least, is a relatively safe bet, since no human language can work without **something** (= obviously, not necessarily an *and*-like word!) that **minimally** licenses the expression of 'molecular facts/propositions' like [p & q] (where p, q are propositions that name events or states of affairs). Whether a 'group-forming/comitative' function **C** is also universally necessary is much less obvious, in my view.

However, even that radically abstractive step would not be enough if what motivates your question is the need to understand the situation in Mandarin, where the '?coordinators' we need to render as English *and* do **not** really correspond, either in intrinsic meaning or in syntactic category, to English *and* at all, and where, viceversa, our English *and*s have to be rendered in Mandarin in terms of completely different things (?prepositions, sentence adverbs, particles, (correlative) verbs, [floating] quantifiers, or even 'zero', i.e.,'pragmatic' devices like sheer juxtaposition, with or without ellipsis for economy's sake, etc.).

The obvious problem with English *and* (and its counterparts in other IE languages) - as opposed to our hypothetical function **&** - is that, even when it conjoins clauses, it is often far from being a 'pure' propositional conjunction function. A second, related, problem, of course, is that, at surface level at least, English *and* (like its nearest IE counterparts) can also 'conjoin' DPs/NPs, and, in general, XPs, X's and even Xs, and one of the  consequences is that when it 'conjoins' DPs/NPs, it **sometimes** (**but not in all cases!**) is close in meaning to the preposition *with* (and to the would-be universal 'comitative/group-forming function' **C**).

As to the former problem, we can approximate English *and* to a genuinely universal conjunction function **&** if we disregard the various 'adverbial' (e.g., temporal, causal, contrastive, etc.) implications that *and* may have and take into consideration only its truth-conditional contribution as a pure propositional function, which we can do by means of a careful choice of examples, cf. below. As to the second issue, of course, the only way to establish the real import of *and* as a '?coordinator' of NPs/DPs, etc. is to distinguish between 'surface' and 'deep' coordination, which in its turn entails calculating the 'Logical Forms' of the constructions involved in each case.

Consider, for example, the following English cases of 'surface' [NP *and* NP] coordination and their possible interpretations:

(1) *John **and** Mary died*. If we adhere to the abstractive strategy of counting only truth-conditional meaning, (1) has **only one** interpretation: it claims the existence of **two** death events with one participant each (= John died, Mary died = Mary died, John died). No particular time sequence or 'groupal/comitative' implication between the two deaths can be legitimately deduced from (1), so *and* is a pure ***&*** function here, in spite of the fact that, at surface level, it conjoins **two NPs** instead of two clauses.

(2) *John **and** Mary played the flute*. Again, (2) has just **one** interpretation: it claims the existence of 2 flute-playing events (or sets of such events!) with **one participant each** (= John played the flute, Mary played the flute = Mary played the flute, John played the flute). Again, no time sequence, nor 'groupal/comitative' nuance, is entailed by (2), so *and* remains a pure **&** function here, as well, in spite of being a (surface) NP-coordinator.

(3) *John **and** Mary played the piano*. In this case, on the contrary, **two** interpretations are possible. According to interpretation (3a), (3) says that there are **two** piano-playing events (or sets of such events) with **one** participant each (= John played the piano, Mary played the piano = Mary played the piano, John played the piano) but nothing follows from (3) as to the order in which each piano playing event occurred. According to interpretation (3b), on the contrary, (3) claims the existence of just **one** piano-playing event **with two participants** (John and Mary playing together, four hands).

(4) *John **and** Mary married*. Again, (4) has **two** possible interpretations. According to interpretation (4a), (4) claims the existence of **two** separate wedding events (with four participants = John plus somebody else different from Mary, and Mary plus somebody else different from John), and, again, nothing can be legitimately inferred from (4) as to the order in which the two weddings occurred. According to interpretation (4b), on the contrary, (4) claims the existence of just **one** wedding, with John and Mary as the main participants (= John married Mary = Mary married John).

(5) *John and Mary argued*, finally, has only **one** interpretation: there has been just **one** discussion event (or, possibly, a set of repeated discussion events of exactly the same type) with John and Mary as participants (= John argued **with** Mary = Mary argued **with** John), **not two** discussion events/sets of events with one participant each (John or Mary, respectively). In other words, the 'comitative' interpretation is the only one available here.

Now, as far as I know, the Mandarin (?preposition) *he2* (alternatively: *yu3* or *gen1*, with some regional variation, apparently) can translate the (broadly) 'groupal/comitative' reading of English *and* in sentence (5) and in sentences (3) and, possibly, (4) when they have the interpretations (3b) and (4b), respectively, but, to my knowledge, none of them can translate *and* in sentences (1), (2), or even (3) when the latter has the interpretation (3a), that is, whenever **two** separate events are involved.

To replicate such English (surface!) [NP *and* NP] coordination cases, Mandarin must resort to **other** devices which semantically approximate English *and* (to the extent it reduces to universal **&**), but clearly differ from English *with* - or from our hypothetical universal 'groupal/comitative' function **C**. In particular, Mandarin can use the 'sentence adverb' *ye3* (= also, as well) - assuming *ye3* cannot be analysed as an intra-sentential conjunction - or, possibly, *you4….you4* (= 'both … and…/not only… but also…', provided the surface 'coordinates' are phrasal, not clausal). All other choices, as far as I know, have **non**-truth-functional (e.g., temporal, concessive, causal,...etc.) implications (e.g., *ránhòu* = 'and then', *háishi* = 'nevertheless', 'still', *suo3yi3* = 'so', 'as a consequence', etc.), and, to that extent, they 'say' (and imply) **more** than English *and* **in the examples above**.

Since my knowledge of Mandarin is only elementary, there may well be even gross factual inaccuracies in the discussion above, but they do not worry me too much, as I expect any factual errors of mine will be immediately corrected by the specialists in Mandarin in this forum. That quick, and necessarily selective, discussion was included here only as an example of the way you could yourself proceed to answer your own question in a systematic way: the real point I wished to make above is just that, provided you look not only at 'surface' syntax, but also to 'semantics'/'logical form', English *and* and *with*, as well as Mandarin *hé, yu3, gen1* and *ye3*, *yòu...yòu*, etc., or even a universal **&** function and a (possibly) universal **C** function **can**, indeed, be easily distinguished. Typological distinctions between *and*-languages and *with*-languages in cases of [NP & NP] coordination, on the contrary, in spite of all the nice maps, etc., may **not** suffice for that purpose unless a 'deep' semantic/LF analysis of all the relevant examples has been carried out before positing such language types.

I am no typologist, though, and I do not know whether that has been the case or not, so please do **not** interpret me as saying anything **against** typological studies; on the contrary, they are **the only way** to approach questions like yours, but they must include deep semantic (LF) analysis, not just inspection and comparison of 'surface' syntactic structures.

Comment: Thanks for the work. Monumental! Just what I've been looking for.